# Change the profile of the wireframe modifier?

Tags: wireframe

I have a simple question.
Is it possible to change or define the profile of the wireframe modifier to a cylinder for example? I tried subdividing however it breaks the shape and it does not give me the desired effect.

Thank you in advance, I hope I was clear!

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can. If you have a rather light base mesh you can try to use the skin modifier + either a subdivision surface modifier or a bevel modifier, but it will create a lot of extra geometry in the process.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the only possible way would be replacing the generated wireframe with bezier curves by hand or with the help of code... I hope this comes in the future versions as a possibility!  Thank you anyways!